# Getting a GPS coordinate from a text hint of the location?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, gps

I am working on a location-based service platform, that will be coordinate based. In ideal situations, I can have the GPS grab the coordinates. However, I would like to have a fallback where I would have an autocompleting text field in which a user can input the address/name of the place. The autocomplete dialog would try to make a smart guess what the place is, just like how it would work in Google Maps when you try to search for a location.

Is there an API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/).

There is also a [handy jQuery plugin called geo-autocomplete](http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/) that can help you with this.

See also the [Google example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html), and [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Autocomplete).